# How do I add JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, 8

I'm creating a website and I want to display a widget from another website inside a block.

In the widget description, I have this information:

> Paste this code at the top of your website code, with the other JS
>   includes. If you are already loading jQuery, please remove it from the
>   code below and only load the widgets.js
>
> ```
> <script async src="https://widgets.nitropanel.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> ```
>
> Paste the following code where you want your widget to appear on your
>   website, note that the widget is 100% width, so you will need to
>   contain it.
>
> ```
>      <div class="nitrous-widget" data-server-id="NN63197376" data-theme="green" data-refresh="10"></div>
> ```

How do I include this first code inside the header (or footer)?

Answer (score 1):

Your canonical reference for this is [here](https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets). In short:

1. Save the CSS or JS to a file. (I normally do this at
   `docroot/themes/projecttheme_directory/js/`)
2. Define a "library", which can contain both CSS and JS files.
3. "Attach" the library to a render array in a hook.

You can add these files globally, (see **"Attaching to all pages"**) or to specific pages or blocks, (**Attaching a library in a Twig template**) There's a good deal of flexibility in how you can add your javascript, so be sure to review all the options listed there.